# Filter list based on id

Tags: list, flutter, filter

How to get id from list?

I have two list

```
List<Level> levelList;
List<Unit> unitList;
```

This is the levelList item

```
[Level(id: 1 name: level1, levelNo: null), Level(id: 2, name: level2, levelNo: null)]
```

This is the `unitList` item

```
[Unit(id: null, levelId: 1,unitName: A-01-01), Unit(id: null, levelId: 2,  unitName: A-01-02), Unit(id: null, levelId: 1, unitName: A-01-03),Unit(id: null, levelId: 3, unitName: A-02-03), Unit(id: null, levelId: 3, unitName: A-02-04),]
```

How can I filter the `unitList` which `levelId` same with the id in `levelList`?

**Expected Output**

```
   [Unit(id: null, levelId: 1,unitName: A-01-01), Unit(id: null, levelId: 2,  unitName: A-01-02), Unit(id: null, levelId: 1, unitName: A-01-03)]
```

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: @LeiYang it's Dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
List<Unit> tempList = [];
  unitList.forEach((element) {
    levelList.forEach((element1) {
      if (element1.id == element.levelId) {
        tempList.add(element);
      }
    });
  });
```

it will work